# How to enable auto save when switch to terminal in webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Is there a way to tell WebStorm that it should auto save a file when switching from code window in to WebStorms terminal window. As I run my test from the WebStorm terminal I offen fix a test, switch to terminal, run the test  and the test is failing again cause the changes wasn't saved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell WebStorm that it should auto save a file when switching from code window in to WebStorm's terminal window.

Not yet:

1) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118481 
2) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118545 
3) http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118846 
etc. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23Terminal+save